# Complex Formulas within Excel Using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on vba code where I have data (for Slope Inclinometers) at various depths like so:

```
Depth   A0  A180    Checksum    B0  B180    Checksum

4.5 (-1256) 1258    2   (-394)  378 (-16)

4.5 (-1250) 1257    7   (-396)  376 (-20)

4.5 (-1257) 1257    0   (-400)  374 (-26)

Depth   A0  A180    Checksum    B0  B180    Checksum

5   (-1214) 1214    0   (-472)  459 (-13)

5   (-1215) 1212    -3  (-472)  455 (-17)

5   (-1216) 1211    -5  (-473)  455 (-18)
```

UNKNOWN AMOUNT OF DATA WILL BE PRESENT (depends how much the user transfers to this sheet)

Now I need to be able to calculate the A Axis Displacement, the B Axis Displacement, and the resultant which have formulas as followed:

A Axis Displacement = [((A0-A180)/2)-((A0*-A180*)/2))]*(constant/constant)

Where * is the initial readings which is always the first row of data at that specified depth.

B Axis Displacement = [((A0-A180)/2)-((A0*-A180*)/2))]*(constant/constant)

Where * is the initial readings which is always the first row of data at that specified depth.

Resultant = SQRT[(A Axis Displacement)^2 + (B Axis Displacement)^2]

I'm struggling to find examples of how I can implement this using vba as there will be various depths present (unknown amount) on the same sheet where the formula will need to start over at each new depth present.

Any helps/tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how I can implement this using vba as there will be various depths present...

You still can do it purely with formulas and easy auto-fill, because the formula *can* find the the first occurrence of the current depth and perform all the necessary calculations, leaving blank at header rows or blank rows. For instance, you can enter these formulas at row 2 and fill down all the rows.

```
H2 (A Axis Displacement):
=IF(ISNUMBER($A2),0.5*(B2-C2-VLOOKUP($A2,$A:$F,2,0)+VLOOKUP($A2,$A:$F,3,0)), "")

I2 (B Axis Displacement):
=IF(ISNUMBER($A2),0.5*(E2-F2-VLOOKUP($A2,$A:$F,5,0)+VLOOKUP($A2,$A:$F,6,0)), "")

J2 (Resultant):
=IF(ISNUMBER($A2),SQRT(SUMSQ(H2,I2)),"")
```

p.s. in the displacements formulas I omitted the (constant/constant) factor as it is irrelevant to the answer, you can easily multiply the `0.5` factor by anything you need.

[image]